# PHP PDO does not throw exception on duplicate key insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a strange problem with PDO not throwing an exception when a duplicate value is inserted. In this case I did expect an error.

The relevant code:

```
try
{
  $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$config["database"]["hostname"].";charset=utf8", $config["database"]["username"], $config["database"]["password"], []);
  $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db_conn->exec(file_get_contents("some_file_with_data.sql");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  // PDOException extends RuntimeException extends Exception so exceptions should be catched here
  // however for the duplicate key entry it will not throw an exception
}
```

The file with SQL data contains multiple inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO `a` (`b`, `c`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 2);

INSERT INTO `a` (`b`, `c`) VALUES
  (1, 1);
```

The field `b` in table `a` is set to being the primary key. When I insert the exact same data in the exact same structure using phpMyAdmin I get this error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '65533' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Why does PDO not throw an error in this case? Even when I set the error mode to exception?

Edit:
This is the table structure used for this specific table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `b` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `c` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102644/pdo-exception-questions-how-to-catch-them

Comment: I already have it in a try/catch block, let me update my code to clarify this.

Comment: What's the exact constraint set on the table?

Comment: @deceze I've updated my question with the table structure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2018: DEVs do not consider this a bug, but intended behaviour.
So, PHP-Users have to live with that, Report is closed for any future questions...**

This has often been reported as bug with `PDO`: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61613

It will only throw an exception if the **FIRST** Statement is invalid. If the first statement runs smooth, you won't get any error - And your first statement is valid:

```
INSERT INTO `a` (`b`, `c`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 2);
```

as a workaround - or according to *user deleted* the right way of doing it -  you need to process the rowsets one-by-one (taken from the bug reports comments):

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    while ($statement->nextRowset()) {/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61613 */};
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't completely sure my code was 100% correct but I did never find this bug report (who searches for "No PDO error if first SQL statement of a group is valid" when you do not get an exception on a duplicate entry :P )