# PHP PDO output user-defined Exceptions

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, pdo, exception

I've got a (example) Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXCEPTION_TEST
  RETURN NUMBER
AS 
BEGIN
  raise_application_error(-20500, 'This is the exception text I want to print.');
END;
```

and I call it in PHP with PDO with the following code:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT exception_test() FROM dual');
$statement->execute();
```

The call of the function works perfectly fine, but now I want to print the Exception text only.

I read somewhere, that you should not use try and catch with PDO. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have read that you shouldn't catch an error to *report* it.

However, if you want to *handle* it somehow, it's all right to catch it.

Based on the example from my article on [handling exception in PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch),

```
try {
    $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT exception_test() FROM dual');
    $statement->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 20500 ) {
        echo $e->getmessage();
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Here you are either getting your particular error or re-throwing the exception back to make it handled the usual way

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll do it in this way now. However, it's not possible to get the exception text only, or is it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. you want this text as a function's output?

Comment: Yeah. I want to output the exception text ('This is the exception text I want to print.') to the user, because I'm doing error detection in the SQL Stored Procedures and Functions. The 'getMessage' method prints a whole lot of stuff, but I only want to get the exception text. Is splitting the message to get only the exception text the only way to achieve this?

Comment: I  am afraid yes,

Answer (score 0):

You check the execute response and get the error, for example, like this:

```
if ($statement->execute() != true) {
    echo $statement->errorCode();
    echo $statement->errorInfo();
}
```

You can find more options at the [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Okay, thank you. That works. Now I get the following output: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20500 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20500: This is the exception text I want to print. ORA-06512: at "EPCOS.EXCEPTION_TEST", line 5 (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\test.php(9): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\test.php on line 9`

How can I only print the exception text (This is the exception...)?

Comment: Well, if you want to handle the specific exceptions, then you use `try/catch` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102644/pdo-exception-questions-how-to-catch-them). If you want to know, if the result was a success, then you use a simple `if`.

Comment: So, you mean that it's not possible to get the exception text and I have to check if the exception has the code (-20500) and print the text with PHP?