# LIKE in SQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I'm using a PDO to run this query, is there a way to see if the query return false? and why my query return nothing when I expect a result?

```
                $selectsql = "SELECT `firstname`,`surname`,`phone`,`address`,`username`,`StudentID` FROM `student_info` WHERE ? LIKE ?";
                $selectstmt = $conn->prepare($selectsql);
                $selectstmt->execute(array($searchby,"%{$searchval}%"));
                while($data = $selectstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                  echo "
                  <tr>
                    <td>{$data['firstname']}</td>
                    <td>{$data['surname']}</td>
                    <td>{$data['phone']}</td>
                    <td>{$data['address']}</td>
                    <td>{$data['username']}</td>
                    <td>Delete Account</td>                    
                  </tr>
                  ";
                  var_dump($data);
                }
```

I var dumpped the `$searchby` and the `$searchval` and they seems fine to me, no mistype or whatsoever.

Comment: you need to something like this LIKE 'name'  you forget to put single quotas

Comment: always remember like is look like this '%searchval%' in a real query

Comment: Is it `"%'{$searchval}'%"` or `"'%{$searchval}%'"`? I tried both but nothing seems to work

Comment: What is `$searchby` ? It *looks* like that should be a field name; and you can't bind fields as parameters.

Comment: `WHERE ?` that is where your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is here :

```
$selectsql = "SELECT firstname`,`surname`,`phone`,`address`,`username`,`StudentID` FROM `student_info` WHERE ? LIKE ?";
```

That placeholder after `where` is messing up your query, after the where clause there should be a column name, by the way I see `$searchby` changes based on the item selected by the user. 
One thing you should note is that :

> **Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.**

Your query should look like.

```
<?php

$search = "%".$searchval."%";
$selectsql = "SELECT `firstname`,`surname`,`phone`,`address`,`username`,`StudentID` FROM `student_info` WHERE $searchby LIKE ?";
    $selectstmt = $conn->prepare($selectsql);
    $selectstmt->execute([$search]);
    $results = $selectstmt->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    if(count($results) > 0){
      var_dump($results);
        foreach($results as $data):?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $data['firstname'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data['surname'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data['phone'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data['address'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data['username'];?></td>
              <td>Delete Account</td>                    
        </tr>

      <?php
          endforeach;
    }else{

      echo "no results found";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

The first and biggest issue is that you **assume** your query is correct, so you do not check for any sql errors. PDO provides extensive exception handling (see [PDO Exception Questions - How to Catch Them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102644/pdo-exception-questions-how-to-catch-them) question here on SO).

This would tell you that you cannot use a parameter to substitute for a field name in  prepared statement. Why? Because the way prepared statements work is that MySQL compiles them and prepares their execution plan. If a field or table is not known at a compile time, then MySQL can't prepare the execution plan either. This means that you cannot have

```
WHERE ? LIKE ?
```

in a prepared statement, you **must** provide the field name in the query. So, you can have

```
WHERE address LIKE ?
```

But fix the exception handling first because that would enable you to get the actual error message.