# PDO Select Statement Syntax Error with Varchar, works with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been staring over this code for quite awhile now and I can't seem to get it to work at all, I have a prepared statement as follow

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Session WHERE SessionId = :sessionID');
  $stmt->bindParam(':sessionID',$sessionID);
  $stmt->execute();
  $session = $stmt->fetch();
```

I have tried various things such as putting single quotes around the ':sessionID' and that prevents the syntax error but leads to nothing being taken from the database. I have ran many of these queries in the database on PHPMyAdmin and they run perfectly fine, I even have tried the generated PHP code from PHPMyAdmin but that produced syntax errors as well. I also tried `PDO::PARAM_STR` and that didn't make any changes. I'm not sure what else to try at this point, I'm running PHP 7.0.28 if that helps. The error is `'* FROM Session WHERE SessionId='5ac81e5ab16089.68567115''`

Comment: add `$stmt->debugDumpParams();` after `$stmt->execute();`. What does it print?

Comment: It outputs this. `SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM Session WHERE SessionId = :sessionID Params: 1 Key: Name: [10] :sessionID paramno=-1 name=[10] ":sessionID" is_param=1 param_type=2 `

Comment: After you execute() call `$arr = $stmt->errorInfo();print_r($arr);`. What does it print?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Does it mean that there are no errors? `var_dump($session);` What's inside?

Comment: Well there is the `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: ` but when I `var_dump($session);` there is stuff in it, which surprised me because when I add single quotes around the parameter there is no PDOException but $session contains false. This is what session has `array(6) { ["SessionId"]=> string(23) "5ac825f52b8a12.42010038" [0]=> string(23) "5ac825f52b8a12.42010038" ["UserID"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "2" ["Expiration"]=> string(19) "2018-04-07 21:59:17" [2]=> string(19) "2018-04-07 21:59:17" } `

Comment: If you put the query into `try{}catch{}` block and output the exception message: what does it print? [PDO Exception Questions - How to Catch Them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102644/pdo-exception-questions-how-to-catch-them)

Comment: I think, it's better to put `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`  into fetch to remove duplication.

Comment: I added `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and attempted to try and catch the error, but I'm still getting the uncaught exception, I followed the stackoverflow post provided just to make sure.

Comment: My goal is to find the cause of the exception. I'll be in the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168434/discussion-between-user4035-and-lramos15).